# SQL - Optimize the execution time

Tags: sql, sql-server, data.stackexchange.com

I am trying to fetch data from stackexchange database. My query is:

```
select distinct top 50 U.Id, U.DisplayName, U.Reputation,
       Tags = stuff( (SELECT ','+p2.Tags 
                       FROM posts p2 join votes V on p2.id = V.PostId
                       where V.VoteTypeId=5 and V.UserId = U.id
                       order by p2.CreationDate DESC
                       FOR XML PATH, TYPE).value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)')
                    ,1,1,'')
from Users U 
order by U.Reputation DESC;
```

However, when I run the query on data.stackexchange.com, it shows an error saying:`Execution Timeout Expired.` Is there any way that I can modify the query to optimize the execution time so that I can run this query successfully?

Comment: Post the execution plan here https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ and share it in the question. Also add the `index` details

Comment: I dont have the offline data from the database I dont know how to get the execution plan online through stackexchange database, could you let me know how to? @Pரதீப்

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need exclude subqueries with individual XML. This will require building common XML with structure `<user ...><tag1><tag2>...</user><user>...` (using [EXPLICIT MODE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/xml/use-explicit-mode-with-for-xml)). And parse it to rows for individual user's.

```
with U as(
    select top 50 id, Reputation, DisplayName
      from users order by Reputation DESC
),
V as(
 select U.*,p2.Tags, p2.CreationDate
  from U, posts p2, votes V
 where p2.id = V.PostId and V.VoteTypeId=5 and V.UserId = U.id
),
Q(XML) as(
    select tag,parent,id [user!1!id],Reputation [user!1!Reputation],Name [user!1!Name], T [T!2!!element]
      from (
        select 1 tag, NULL parent, U.id, U.Reputation, U.DisplayName Name, NULL t, NULL dt
          from U
         union all
        select 2, 1, V.id, NULL, NULL, ','+Tags, CreationDate
          from V
     ) X
     order by id, tag, dt desc
       for xml explicit, type
)
select node.value('(@id)[1]','int'),
       node.value('(@Reputation)[1]','int'),
       node.value('(@Name)[1]','nvarchar(max)'),
       stuff(node.value('.[1]','nvarchar(max)'),1,1,'')
  from Q
 cross apply XML.nodes('/user') as Y(node)
 order by 2 desc
```

Comment: Thank you! It works! But when I try to retrieve `top 5000`, it can be case where expectation timeout. Could you help me retrieve the top 5000 rows?

Comment: @LeoLi For top 5000 users there are 500k voices, this is too much for unloading.